# Adding logic to a sub form in Access?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I have a sub form in Access:
[image]
[image]

The CopyNo is a combobox that lets me select from the MovieCopies table. When I select one, I want the Title field to show the correct movie title associated to that copy's movie ID. I also want the format to show. When I select from DaysRented combobox, if I select 1 and the movie is New, I want it to display the price, if it is regular for 3 days display the correct price etc.

I'm just not sure how to give logic to the comboboxes.

If anyone could point me in the right direction of how to do this sort of thing in Access 2007 I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem? Because without an answer, this question isn't helping anyone

Comment: The data tab has a change event.  When you select a movie from CopyNo it will fire allowing you to place code to update the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

by using either `Before update` or `After Update` events, you can fire the appropriate code to fill in the blanks